# Finding the square root of a random number with Newton's method, using While/Do/For loops?

Tags: programming

I am trying to construct a program that will find the square root of a number, using Newton's method, which is

$$x(n+1) = x_n- f(x) / f'(x_n)$$

The number, will be a random number, generated by: `RandomInteger[{1000000, 10000000}]`

I am setting the first Newton estimate to be 1, so I can iterate my loop until the difference in the estimate from Newton's method after n iterations to the first estimate of 1, being less than 0.001. Since I am trying to construct this fully, I am not using any `Sqrt[x]` function or $n^.5$ relationship either.

My current thoughts:

So I have set:

```
f[x]:=x^2 + k
```

where

```
k = RandomInteger[{1000000, 10000000}]
```

Since I want to know what number I am taking the SQRT of, I am Printing that information out with:

```
Print["The Square Root of ", k, " is ", ---]
```

where --- will be my program.

Since I need to take an unknown number of iterations, I am thinking of using a `For` loop, as that checks the loop invariant condition until it is `False` then stops. This is the part I am stuck on -- what I can't grasp: how do I make the loop check for a condition that is outside of the loop?

Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's wholly unclear what you are asking -- what is it "outside the loop" that you need to check? Also, what's the role of your function `f`: what does this have to do with your question? In order to find `x` for which `x^2 == k`, you want equivalently `x^2 - k == 0`, so the function to iterate is `f[x_] := x^2 - k`. (And you have the syntax for defining `f` wrong: you missed the pattern character `_` in the left-hand side.)

Comment: Why do you want to use a `For` loop? You can just use `Nest` or `NestWhile`, or if you want to see all the iterates, `NestList` or `NestWhileList`.

Or is this homework exercise where somebody is forcing you to use explicitly a `For` loop? If so, you cannot expect us to do your homework for you; at the very least you need to show us the code you already have for the iteration with `For`.

Comment: @murray my initial understanding of Newton's Method was poor, I am correcting my attempts with the suggestions you made, thank you. (The syntax was wrong due to a missed typing error when I was trying to format correctly, I apologize) Also, I don't "need" to use all of those loops, those are just the ones at my disposal at this point, so I was wondering any combination/use of any of them.

Comment: The way the question stands, you are asking for us to create a Newton's Method algorithm using "Do/While/For" loops. However, it is much more functional and cogent to utilize the recursive elements of the function with `NestWhile`. Unless your aim really is to use only those three looping functions, could you please edit your question to be less specific about which functions to use?

Comment: One of the "Applications" given in the [help for `Nest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Nest.html) shows how to perform a fixed number of Newton-Raphson iterations to find $\sqrt{2}$. Use `NestWhile`, as suggested by @Murray, to make this more flexible. `NestWhileList` will return the intermediate results.

Comment: Take a look at file `Hero.nb` from https://www.math.umass.edu/~murray/My_Web_sites/NERCOMP/nercomp.html. It shows various approaches to the problem with Mathematica. The additional notebook `Newton.nb` at that page shows Newton's method more generally. Over the years I've used those, or similar, notebooks as part of an introduction to Mathematica, or as a means for comparing Mathematica with standard (and some more obscure) programming languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a more "traditional" solution, you can try a `While` with a `Break[]` (Your Fortran friends will understand this better ;)

```
z = 81.;  (*number to take its square root*)
f[x_] := x^2 - z;
fd[x_] := 2 x;
x0 = 1;  (*initial guess *)

While[True,
 x1 = x0 - f[x0]/fd[x0];
 If[Abs[x1 - x0] < 0.001, Break[]];
 x0 = x1
 ]
```

check

```
x1
(* 9.000000000007093`*)
```

Or to make it a little more robust, you always add a guard against run-away-cases and use a flag

```
z = 81.;  (*number to take its square root*)
f[x_] := x^2 - z;
fd[x_] := 2 x;
x0 = 1;  (*initial guess *)
maxIterations = 20;
keepSearching = True;
iter = 0;
rootWasFound = False;

While[keepSearching,
  x1 = x0 - f[x0]/fd[x0];
  If[Abs[x1 - x0] < 0.001 || iter > maxIterations,
   If[Abs[x1 - x0] < 0.001, rootWasFound = True];
   keepSearching = False
   ,
   x0 = x1;
   iter++
   ]
  ];
```

now

```
If[rootWasFound,
 Print["root ", x1, " was found in ", iter, " iterations"],
 Print["No root was found, try increasing max iterations "]
 ]
```

gives

```
 root 9. was found in 6 iterations
```

Comment: oh better use a goto for the Fortran folks.... While[Abs[f[x0]] > .0001, x0 -= f[x0]/fd[x0];]

Comment: superb, thank you. I was wondering at first about the break as well, and ended up finishing it within the If

Answer (score 7):

As you have defined in your question, Newton's Method gives us the next value in the iteration by following the tangent of the curve you are approximating.

Thus, we can create a function (using your `f[x_, sq_] = x^2 - sq`) that gives us the next `x` value when looking for the square root of `sq`.

```
getNext[x_, sq_] = x - f[x, sq]/D[f[x, sq], x];
```

(Notice I do not use delayed set so that the derivative is evaluated only once)

Now, instead of a `For`-loop, which usually calls for a definite number of iterations, or even a `While`-loop, which uses just a test as an ending condition, I recommend using [`NestWhile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NestWhile.html), which, appropriately, nests a function on an expression until the given test fails.

The testing function and recursive function to be nested are passed as pure functions.

```
sqrt[sq_, start_: 1.] := NestWhile[getNext[#, sq]&, start, Abs[f[#, sq]] > .001 &]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
 nwt[k_, tol_: (10^-4)] := Row[{"The Square Root of ", k, " is ", 
  N@FixedPoint[(# + k/#)/2 &, 1,  SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < tol &)]}]
 nwt /@ RandomInteger[{10, 100}, {10}] // Column
```

[image]