# How many iterations of Newton's method are needed to achieve a given precision?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, iterators

Consider using Newton's method to solve the equation $arctan(x) = 0$. Using an initial guess of $x_0 = 1/2$ produces a sequence that converges rapidly. After $8$, iterations, $x_8$ is accurate to well over 2000 decimal places.

> (i) Verify with a computer that $x_8$ is a solution accurate to over $2000$ decimal
>   places.

I was just learning Newton's Method and saw this problem. I think I might be going ahead but it seems good to know.

Here is my attempt: (Sorry if I'm wrong. I am just really interested in this problem)

```
         In[1]:newton1[function_, variable_, initial_, iterations_] :=
               Module[{p, f, x},
               Subscript[p, 1] = initial;
               f[x_] := function /. variable -> x;
               Do[
               Subscript[p, i] = 
               Subscript[p, i - 1] - 
               f[Subscript[p, i - 1]]/f'[Subscript[p, i - 1]];,
               {i, 2, iterations}];
               Subscript[p, iterations]
               ]

               In[1]:Timing[approx = newton1[arctan(x)=0, x, 1/2, 8]]

               Out[1]:{0.826805, Indeterminate}
```

or I was wondering if the program could be this:

```
              In[1]: f[x_] := arctan[x] = 0;

              In[1]: mynewton[function_, variable_, initial_, iterations_] :=
                     Module[{f, x, p},
                     f[x_] := function /. variable -> x;
                     Subscript[p, 1] = initial;
                     Do[
                     Subscript[p, i] = 
                     Subscript[p, i - 1] - 
                     f[Subscript[p, i - 1]]/f'[Subscript[p, i - 1]];,
                     {i, 2, iterations}];
                     Table[Subscript[p, i], {i, 1, iterations}]
                     ]

              In[1]: N[mynewton[f[x], x, 1/2, 8], 8]

              Out[1]: {0.50000000, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, \
                      Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate}
```

Again sorry if I am wrong. I am really interested in learning this part of the program. I will be able to continue to other questions like this after help with this one on my own. I really did try. I was studying various types of Newton's Programs but can not figure this one out. Can someone please help write the input?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19655/finding-the-square-root-of-a-random-number-with-newtons-method-using-while-do

Answer (score 1):

I have a hard time following your code, but it doesn't look to me that you are on the right path. Here is how I would tackle this problem.

```
f[x_] := ArcTan[x]
df[x_] = f'[x];
iterStep[x_] := x - f[x]/df[x]
root = With[{n = 8}, Nest[iterStep, 1/2, n]];

Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 4000}, Abs @ root < 10^-2500]
```

> True

```
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 4000}, Abs @ root < 10^-2600]
```

> False

I interpret the last two results as saying that `root` approximates zero to more than 2500 decimal places, but less than 2600 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

Of course m_goldberg has the proper mathematica-esque soluiton, but for education purpose heres a working version of your loop approach..

```
    newton1[function_, variable_, initial_, iterations_] := Module[{p, f},
      p[1] = initial;
      f[x_] := function /. variable -> x; 
      Do[p[i] = p[i - 1] - f[p[i - 1]]/f'[p[i - 1]] // N;, {i, 2, 
           iterations}]; p[iterations] ];


  newton1[ArcTan[x], x, 1/2, 8]
```

Explicit use of Subscript[] is usually not a good idea.. , and you had a bunch of other issues. 
Note also there is no reason to actually carry around all the p[i..] except the last one, but i left that alone

Answer (score 1):

`Nest` seems perfect for Newton's method.

```
newtonStep[f_] := # - f[#]/f'[#] &;
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 5000},
 N[Nest[newtonStep[ArcTan], 1/2, 8], 10]
 ]

(* 8.829190025*10^-2598 *)
```

With `NestList`, you can observe the convergence.

```
newtonStep[f_] := # - f[#]/f'[#] &;
Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 5000},
  N[NestList[newtonStep[ArcTan], 1/2, 8], 10]
  ]

(* { 0.5000000000,
    -0.07955951125,
     0.0003353022040,
    -2.513147366*10^-11, 
     1.058187453*10^-32,
    -7.899444718*10^-97, 
     3.286233612*10^-289,
    -2.365941712*10^-866,
     8.829190025*10^-2598} *)
```

A gain in speed may obtained by computing approximate results all along.  I found that to get a single significant digit in the 8th iterate, I could do without the extra precision, but I needed to start with 2600 digits of precision.  To get the results above, I needed 2610.

```
NestList[newtonStep[ArcTan], 0.5`2610, 8] //  N[#, 10] &
```

*Remark:* The convergence rate is unusually fast (cubic instead of quadratic) because the second derivative of `ArcTan` is zero at the root.

Comment: wanted to note a subtle thing here: NestList operates symbolically resulting is a huge expression of nested ArcTan expressions, which is evaluated numerically at the end by the N[] wrapper. It runs way faster with essentiually the same precision if you put an N inside the newtonStep function.. `newtonStep[f_]:=N[#-f[#]/f'[#],500]&;`

Comment: @george2079 Interesting:  I knew the exact expression would grow very large, but it didn't seem slow enough to worry about.  Testing your comment, I found this: It turns out on the beta V10 I was using, there is essentially no difference in speed, exact vs approximate, `0.005981` vs. `0.005963`.  But on V9, it's about `2.7` vs. `0.0075`.  On the other hand, I found 500 digits of precision insufficient for more than 6 iterations.