# Newton's Method

Tags: equation-solving, function-construction, numerics, homework

Problem statement:

[image]

I'm currently new to Mathematica and have been trying to solve this problem. I was digging around and found this code:

```
newtonmethod[error_, initial_, maxiteration_, errorpower_] := 
  Module[{},
    g[x_] := D[f[x], x];
    h[t_] := t - f[t]/g[t];
    guess = initial;
    tol = error;
    errorset = {};
    ratios = {};
    Do[
      p = h[t] /. t -> guess;
      tol = Abs[p - guess];
      AppendTo[errorset, tol];
      Print["n = ", n, ", x= ", N[ p], ", error =", N[ tol]];
      guess = p; 
      If[tol <= error ∨ Chop[g[t] /. t -> guess] == 0, 
        Goto["errorcalculation"]], 
      {n, 1, maxiteration}];
    Label["errorcalculation"];
    Do[
      AppendTo[ratios, errorset[[i + 1]]/errorset[[i]]^errorpower], 
      {i, 1, Length[errorset] - 1}];
    Print["Here are the error ratios \n"];
    TableForm[N[ratios]]]
```

I'm not really sure on how to use it and/or if it's enough to complete the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define the function for which a zero is desired, for instance, `f[x_] := (x - 1)^2`.  Then, execute `newtonmethod`, for instance, `newtonmethod[.0001, .1, 20, 2]`.

Comment: For your own benefit (be better at using Mathematica), try to do either (1) write your own code, or (2) understand the code; then you ask when you're stuck with doing one of the above.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [(19655)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19655/finding-the-square-root-of-a-random-number-with-newtons-method-using-while-do), [(59877)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59877/implementing-the-newton-raphson-method-for-finding-the-zeros-of-a-function)

Comment: @bbgodfrey I defined my function and then tried to execute newtonmethod and received no output

Comment: Did you enter and execute the code for `newtonmethod ` first?

Comment: @bbgodfrey no I executed the function first, followed by newtonmethod. I don't see an output for the function or newtonmethod

Answer (score 3):

I offer an implementation more of *Mathematica*'s style, I suppose,

```
Clear[findRootByNewton]
findRootByNewton[f : _Symbol | _Function, initPt_Real, η_:1.*^-6] := Module[{df},
   df = Derivative[1][func];
   NestWhileList[# - f[#]/df[#] &, initPt, Abs[Subtract[##]] >= η &, 2]
  ]
```

One needs to provide the function (of pure function form or defined by `SetDelayed (:=)`) whose root to be found, the initial guess and an optional precision goal with a default value of $ 1.0\times 10^{-6} $.

Then I use $ f(x)=x^2-2 $ as an example. Either

```
findRootByNewton[#^2 - 2 &, 1.]
```

or

```
f[x_] := x^2 - 2
findRootByNewton[f, 1.]
```

returns

> ```
> {1., 1.5, 1.41667, 1.41422, 1.41421, 1.41421}
> ```

The result shows root approximations found at each iteration, until the preset precision goal is reached.

---

P.S.

If one just wants the final result, use `NestWhile` instead of `NestWhileList`.

Comment: When trying your code I get an output of the following: {1., 1.+1./func'[1.]} I can't seem to figure out why it's providing me the exact result and not the decimal approximation.

Comment: @JVang10 What is your $ f(x) $, then?